# How do I configure SSH keys in a Vagrant multi-machine setup?

Tags: ansible, vagrant

I have 4 VMs in my Vagrantfile - 3 application servers and an Ansible control host.

I only use Vagrant to create the VMs as I provision them manually from the ansible control host because I am still creating/editing the ansible scripts.

I can do `vagrant ssh ansible` and `vagrant ssh app1/2/3` etc. but when I try to do `ansible-playbook oracle.yml` from the Ansible control host, SSH fails with

```
fatal: [192.168.60.10]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "SSH encountered an unknown error during the connection. We recommend you re-run the command using -vvvv, which will enable SSH debugging output to help diagnose the issue", "unreachable": true}
```

I can successfully ssh from the Ansible VM to the Oracle VM using user vagrant and password vagrant.

The key parts of my Vagrantfile are:

```
config.ssh.insert_key = false

config.vm.define "db" do |db|
    db.vm.box = "boxcutter/ol67"
    db.vm.hostname = "oracle-vm"
    db.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 22, host: 2201, id: "ssh", auto_correct: false
    db.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 1521, host: 1521
    db.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.60.10"
    db.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
        v.name = "oracle-vm"
        v.linked_clone = true
        v.memory = 2048
        v.cpus = 2
    end
end

#Optional ansible control machine for Windows users
config.vm.define "ansible", autostart: false do |ansible|
    ansible.vm.box = "williamyeh/ansible"
    ansible.vm.hostname = "ansible-vm"
    ansible.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 22, host: 2204, id: "ssh", auto_correct: false
    ansible.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.60.50"
    ansible.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
        v.linked_clone = true
    end
    #Mount the project directory on the guest so we can run the playbooks from there
    ansible.vm.synced_folder ".", "/data/ansible", create: true
end
```

What do I need to put in the Vagrantfile to allow the Ansible VM to connect to the other VMs without requiring a password or extra manual steps after `vagrant up`?

This is just for development testing on a private network on developers PCs so security is not really an issue and comes second to ease of implementation and smooth user experience.

Comment: Duplicate of https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/1017/unable-to-ssh-in-a-mutli-machine-vagrant-environment

Comment: I stated quite clearly that I can ssh between VMs it is just that ansible cannot because it requires keys set up. He cannot ssh. The questions are clearly different.

Comment: @JamesShewey: I don't think that any answer for that question is relevant to that. The answer given refers to communications from the host to the guests; the needed answer needs to apply between guests.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on [techraf's 3rd suggestion](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/1241/375) I did the following:

- `vagrant up ansible`
- `ssh-keygen` (no password just pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
- copied `.ssh/id_rsa` and `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to the project directory
- `vagrant destroy ansible`
- modified the `Vagrantfile` to copy the `id_rsa` to all hosts
- modified the `Vagrantfile` to copy the `id_rsa.pub` into `authorized_keys` on all hosts
- modified the Vagrantfile to disable host checking

Vagrantfile snippet:

```
 config.vm.provision "file", source: "id_rsa", destination: "/home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa"
 public_key = File.read("id_rsa.pub")
 config.vm.provision :shell, :inline =>"
     echo 'Copying ansible-vm public SSH Keys to the VM'
     mkdir -p /home/vagrant/.ssh
     chmod 700 /home/vagrant/.ssh
     echo '#{public_key}' >> /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
     chmod -R 600 /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
     echo 'Host 192.168.*.*' >> /home/vagrant/.ssh/config
     echo 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' >> /home/vagrant/.ssh/config
     echo 'UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null' >> /home/vagrant/.ssh/config
     chmod -R 600 /home/vagrant/.ssh/config
     ", privileged: false
```

Comment: This solution worked well for me but I had to change Host 192.168.*.* to just *. Not sure why. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

There is no general method and it might depend on how `boxcutter/ol67` was packed.

1. The easiest method would be to define the password in the Ansible inventory file:

   ```
   [oracle-vm:vars]
   ansible_ssh_user=vagrant
   ansible_ssh_pass=vagrant
   ```
2. The second method would be to leave the insecure private key configured on the `oracle-vm` machine and inject the private key to the `ansible` VM:

   ```
   config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
     ssh_insecure_key = File.readlines("#{Dir.home}/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key").first.strip
     s.inline = <<-SHELL
       echo #{ssh_insecure_key} >> /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa
       chown vagrant /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa
       chmod 400 /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa
     SHELL
   end
   ```
3. Generate the key pair beforehand on the host machine, inject private key to Ansible VM, public key to Oracle's `authorized_keys`.
4. Generate the key pair on Ansible VM, copy the public key to Oracle VM using shell provisioner and inject `vagrant` as password for `ssh-copy-id`.

And the list does not end here, it depends on required security.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a preformatted block within a list, indent by eight spaces:

1. generate public/private key

   ```
   cd vagrant-home
   ssh-keygen // just pressed enter
   copy ~/.ssh/id_rsa .
   copy ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub .
   ```
2. edit Vagrantfile,add follow lines:
           config.vm.provision "file", source: "id_rsa", destination: "/home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa"

   ```
       public_key = File.read("id_rsa.pub")
       config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SCRIPT
           chmod 600 /home/vagrant/.ssh/is_rsa
           echo 'Copying ansible-vm public SSH Keys to the VM'
           #mkdir -p /home/vagrant/.ssh
           chmod 700 /home/vagrant/.ssh
           echo '#{public_key}' >> /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
           chmod -R 600 /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
           echo 'Host 192.168.*.*' >> /home/vagrant/.ssh/config
           echo 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' >> /home/vagrant/.ssh/config
           echo 'UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null' >> /home/vagrant/.ssh/config
           chmod -R 600 /home/vagrant/.ssh/config
           SCRIPT
   ```
3. ```
           vagrant up // or vagrant reload --provision
   ```

Comment: Is this just a reformatted version of my answer? If so you should probably just edit my answer rather than adding a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate the keys using shell provisioner ssh-keygen quiet mode, copy the pub key to the project folder and then copy it to the other(s) machine(s) using file provisioner. Assuming /vagrant/ is the project synced folder, it should be something like this:

```
machine1.vm.provision "shell", inline: "[ ! -f '/home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa' ] && ssh-keygen -q -f /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa -N ''"

machine1.vm.provision "shell", inline: "cp /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa.pub /vagrant/"

machine2.vm.provision "file", source: "id_rsa.pub", destination: "/home/vagrant/.ssh/"

machine2.vm.provision "shell", inline: "[ ! -f '/home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa_machine1.pub' ] && cat /vagrant/id_rsa.pub >> /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys"

machine2.vm.provision "file", source: "id_rsa.pub", destination: "/home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa_machine1.pub"
```